# Android: how to open some app links in a non default browser

Tags: android, android-app-links

This is what I want to achieve (on Android):

I want all links that are not otherwise linked to an app to open in my default browser (Samsung Internet)

This is the default behaviour and how it currently works.

I then want specific types of link to open in Firefox browser. For example, I would like to register youtube.com app links to open in Firefox, not My default browser.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Is there an app I can install that will allow me to set it to open arbitrary app links, and then forward those to another application (in this case, Firefox)

I have found two apps, "better open with" and "open link with" which sort of achieve this by registering themselves as a browser, and if you then set them as the default browser, they then forward all links on woods to the browser of your choice using some form of rules.

What I would like to do is basically the same thing but without having to register another app as the default browser. Instead I want to get only specific app links to open in my non-default browser.

Comment: This is on the line of not being a programming questions, depending on if you're trying to write something like this or just set up your device.  In the second case, it's completely off topic here.  In the first case, you'd have to be the default browser because Android doesn't have a concept of default based on an entire URI, just based on the scheme.

Comment: Is there a better forum to ask which includes allowing existing software tools to be used?

Comment: android.stackexchange.com is a place to just ask android questions.  I don't know all the rules about being on topic there, but this should fall under it.  It's focused more on using Android devices vs programming.

Answer (score 0):

An API known as an "intent filter" allows apps to request that links be opened within the app.

If the app possesses the proper intent filter, you will receive a prompt to open the link using the app, and the app will subsequently take action on it.

Only the app developer can incorporate this feature into their app, and it is not possible for you to add it unless you decompile the app.

The Google+ app is one such app that employs this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is basically the same thing but without having to register another app as the default browser. Instead I want to get only specific app links to open in my non-default browser.

That's not possible. It's why those apps exist.

Comment: There are apps that already exist which work this way for example YouTube. If I install YouTube, then a suite of URLs such as m.youtube.com and YouTube.com open in the YouTube app instead of my default browser.

Comment: Right. A suite of URLs like m.youtube.com and youtube.com that the YouTube app owns and has registered to handle. Any app with an accompanying website will do this. But this is not what you asked - _you_ want to decide which urls get handled by different browsers and that is not possible.

Comment: It clearly is possible, because whoever made the YouTube app did it. Presumably there's nothing stopping the creators of Firefox from making Firefox open YouTube links if they wanted to. So given that it's obviously possible because other people have done it, reread my question and see what I am asking.

Comment: I read your question and quoted it in my answer. I don't know what you think YouTube is doing but it's not what you're asking. What's stopping Firefox from opening YouTube links is that the YouTube app owns those links and is made the default handler of said links by the system. Each app decides what links it'll handle, not you. So given that it's obviously not possible because this is not how Android works, reread my answer and come to terms with it.